# Smooth Transition of Path using Specified Styling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am fairly new to this community, and I'm also not the most articulate person. I hope I'm not upsetting the powers that be by posting a new question. The reason I am posting again is because I have conveyed my original question very poorly. Even after repeated edits the confusion seemed to be irreparable.

My question is as follows:

I would like to use stroke-dasharray (or other means) to animate a path. It's basically a vertical path, no fancy coordinates. From all the examples I've seen, the path that is 'animated' is a solid line. I would like to animate a dotted line styled path.

From my observations, the stroke-dasharray is used as a means to an end to have a smooth animation for a path. If I'm not mistaken, does that mean one can no longer us stroke-dasharraay for styling purposes? Do you have to choose how to utilize it like a zero-sum type of situation, either only animation, or only style?

To reiterate, I'd like to animate using a dotted line styled path, and I'm not sure how to do that, given current examples/ code syntax.

Please advise on what can be brought to bear to animate a dash-styled path's entry as it is appended (in my case when called by a button event). I'd like to have the path be drawn from the bottom to the top with style: `stroke-dasharray, '5,3'`.

This revision has been pre-revised to minimized confusion. I have learned a lot already, and I hope that this question will illuminate those small virtual spaces that have not surfaced yet.

If there is still confusion please feel free to call me out and allow me to clarify.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Sorry I've miss your original question. Have you some jsFiddle or Plunker showing what you got so far?

Comment: Here is a link to a similar graph, imagine something like this, but instead of a fancy loop thing, just a vertical path and a the animated path would need to be a dashed-line, instead of a solid line. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could 'grow' a line making a transition from 0px to total-lenghtpx. Like so:

```
var points = [
  [100, 10],
  [100, 10]
];

var line = d3.svg.line()

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .datum(points)
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("id","grow")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,3")    
    .attr("d", line)
    .transition()
      .duration(7500)                // <-- transition time
      .attr("d", "M100,400L100,10")  // <-- final lenght
```

[Here the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/84op17rh/)

Not the most optimized option. Here's a clean one:

```
<style>
line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dasharray:5 3;
}
</style>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);

svg.append('line')
  .attr({
    x1: 25,
     y1: 400,
    x2: 25,
     y2: 400
  })
  .transition()
  .duration(1500)
  .attr({
    x2: 25,
    y2: 15
  })
</script>
```

- [and the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/pL32g58k/)
- [with a button](https://jsfiddle.net/p3agruqc/)
- [with Scale functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/nevc6jy4/)

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't thought of growing the line like that. I tried it out on my code and it worked. I have two small follow up questions. On my code, before the dashed line is grown, there is a momentary flash of the solid white line. Did you experience this? Not sure what's causing it. Secondly, is there some way to change the `.attr("d", "M100,400L100,10")` to incorporate my existing scale? I tried putting in `.attr("d", function(d) {return scale(d)};` but was unsure what to do with the remaining two arguments that it seemed to need. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Use the second code, its more flexible and you don't need to deal with svg line deffinitions.

Comment: Yea, I see. I like both solutions. Thank you for making it so clear, this was a really tricky one (for me), but you made it look simple